# Can't get remote desktop to open in x11 window through ssh

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, x11

I am having trouble getting an x11 window of the desktop of a remote machine.

I am VPN'ed into a local network and I can get into the computer I want through the command line using:

```
ssh -X computer_name -l login_name
```

I thought that the -X would cause the remote machine's desktop to pop up in x11, and although x11 launched on my mac, I did not get an x11 window of the machines desktop.

I can get things like emacs to run and pop up in new x11 windows, but I want to get the whole desktop going.

I am running Mac OS 10.7, and the remote machine is running linux.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.

after the command

```
ssh -X computer_name -l login_name
```

I had to start a gnome-session

```
gnome-session >&/dev/null &
```

this gave me the linux desktop in an x11 window.

Comment: I recommend using NX if you want to access a full desktop remotely. http://freenx.berlios.de/

Answer (score 3):

`ssh -X` (or `-Y`) only [tunnels](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html) the connection to your local X server for the applications started on the remote machine from your SSH session. It cannot do anything about the desktop environment that is running on the remote machine's own X server.

You're probably looking for something like [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), not X11 forwarding.

Comment: Yeah, the things is that I did this once before through the command line with ssh, and was able to get the remote machine's desktop to open in x11. I just can't remember what command I used.

Comment: Interesting, did the remote desktop open in its own window? Are you sure you weren't running VNC or Xnest over SSH, which is also possible?

Comment: Its possible. I just know that i did it all through the terminal and the desktop came up in x11.

Comment: From what I am reading about doing this through vnc, I'm fairly certain I did not use vnc.

Comment: I figured it out. i had to use the command: <code>gnome-session >&/dev/null & </code>

Comment: Ah, so you're starting a whole Gnome session from the remote end into your local X server. I didn't think of that :) Out of curiosity, how do the multiple panels mesh together in the resulting environment? (Also, you might want to post your comment above as an answer and accept it, it's worth it IMHO.)

Comment: My reputation isn't high enough to accept it, so i have to wait two days, haha. This launched 1 x11 window with the whole linux desktop in it. I ran x11 in full screen and it worked great. The only problem was whenever i went to a different space (or whatever you call the different screens on lion) it would minimize and I would have to open it back up. Also I would sometimes fight with the lion menu bar at the top. So it was glitchy, but overall, it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

X-Window allows you to run programs remotely, and have their windows appear locally on your machine. As you stated, you were able to get this working properly. If you want to see the entire linux desktop on your mac, you will want to use a program like VNC.

You will need to run vncserver on your linux machine, then you can use any of a number of VNC clients on your mac to see the entire linux desktop. For example, [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/files/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your remote Linux desktop to be displayed on a window on your Mac you should use on your Mac (providing that the VPN is already setup and running, you have access to your Linux server, and XDMCP is configured on it):

```
$ Xephyr -query <linux-ip-or-name> :1
```